# model definition debug in django

Tags: python, django

my model definition is below,when I run python manage.py sql application,it comes nothing.
my application name is application. when I change the models' content to the tutorial  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/  ,it comes the right sql sentence,so it must some error in the models below,can anyone point it out?

```
class Applicationinfo(models.Model):
    applicationinfo_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ApplicationInfo_id') # Field name made lowercase.
    mainproduct = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_column='MainProduct') # Field name made lowercase.
    subproduct = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_column='SubProduct') # Field name made lowercase.
    appname = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_column='AppName') # Field name made lowercase.
    employee = models.CharField(max_length=48, db_column='Employee') # Field name made lowercase.
    employeeid = models.CharField(max_length=24, db_column='Employeeid') # Field name made lowercase.
    applicantmail = models.CharField(max_length=90, db_column='applicantMail') # Field name made lowercase.
    mailnotifytimes = models.IntegerField(db_column='MailNotifyTimes') # Field name made lowercase.                                                                                                          
    applicantim = models.CharField(max_length=48, db_column='ApplicantIM') # Field name made lowercase.
    applicantmobilephone = models.CharField(max_length=33, db_column='ApplicantMobilephone') # Field name made lowercase.
    messagenotifytimes = models.IntegerField(db_column='MessageNotifyTimes') # Field name made lowercase.
    applicantdpt = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_column='ApplicantDPT') # Field name made lowercase.
    applicationdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='ApplicationDate') # Field name made lowercase.
    onlinestorid = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column='OnlineStorID') # Field name made lowercase.
    appid = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, db_column='AppID') # Field name made lowercase.
    tapesavecopies = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='TapeSaveCopies', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    appowner = models.CharField(max_length=48, db_column='AppOwner', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    appownermail = models.CharField(max_length=96, db_column='AppOwnerMail', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    subproductowner = models.CharField(max_length=48, db_column='SubProductOwner', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    subproductownermail = models.CharField(max_length=96, db_column='SubProductOwnerMail', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    mainproductowner = models.CharField(max_length=48, db_column='MainProductOwner', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    mainproductownermail = models.CharField(max_length=96, db_column='MainProductOwnerMail', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    applicationreason = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_column='ApplicationReason', blank=True)
    filetype = models.BooleanField(db_column='FileType')
    applicationstatus = models.IntegerField(db_column='ApplicationStatus')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'applicationinfo'
        app_label = 'backupcenter1'
```

Comment: Did you import models correctly? Also, does running python manage.py syncdb come up with an error message?

Comment: yes,if I change the content to the models in the tutorial,it will come correct.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Have you imported the models with from django.db import models , and when you run syncdb, do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

`app_label` is set to `'backupcenter1'`, remove it.

`app_label = 'backupcenter1'` means that, as far as Django knows, this model doesn't belong to your `application` app, but to the `backupcenter1` app. Hence why it does not show up in the SQL output for the `application` app.

---

Also, note that `application` is a terrible name for an application, you might want to change that.

Comment: if I run python manage.py sql backupcenter1,it tells CommandError: App with label backupcenter1 could not be found. Are you sure your INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?

Comment: @young001 I think that `app_label` is telling Django this model belongs to `backupcenter1`, but it's not an app you have, hence the error. Did you try removing the `app_label`?

Comment: @young001 That seems to indicate the app is not listed under INSTALLED_APPS in your settings, which is very likely the problem

Comment: if I remove the app_label,it works well.but I set the app_label is to use multiple database;https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/.so if I remove the app_label,how to use the multiple database?

Comment: @young001 `app_label` defines the app your model belongs to, so if you leave it out, it will be `"application"`. Before using it, I'd recommend you [document yourself on what `app_label` actually does](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label). In your case, you should just add a `backup_center` attribute to `Meta`, and access this attribute form within your DB `Router`: `model._meta.backup_center`. `app_label` is not *just* meant for DB routing.